# Fixing #includes <> for GCC (Code::Blocks)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, codeblocks

I am working with some code that was written for a different compiler/linker, and it is including files like this:

```
#include <Engine/Graphics/Sprite.h>
```

from anywhere in the project.

The project contains such a file at that path (from the root of the project), but when I build I get the file not found error.

How can I fix all of these includes, without going through and doing it all manually?

Comment: add that path to the compiler using `-I`

Comment: You should build with `-I path/to/top/of/build` rather than make every include a relative path

Comment: @Ben this sounds like how I could do it the easiest. how would be the best way to do this in Code::Blocks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your explanation, what do you mean with "from the root of the project". But well...

When you use the #include directive with <> what your are telling the compiler is to look for the the file on the Directories you include with -I option.

In code blocks go to Project->Build Options->Search Directories->Compiler

And add the folder path to the folder containing "Engine".

You can find more info here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4(v=vs.71).aspx

Edit: Before trying anything, try `#include "path/somefile.h"` instead of `#include <pathsomefile.h>`

Answer (score 3):

Probably you should write

```
#include "Engine/Graphics/Sprite.h"
```

(notice the double quotes instead of the brackets).

In `#include` directives brackets are used to specify that you want to include a system/library header file, that will be searched in the system includes directory (e.g. /usr/include), while the double quotes are used to include files in the current path.

This should work if the files that use this `#include` are in the directory that contains the `Engine/...` hierarchy. If that's not the case, you should also specify it to the compiler as an additional include directory, with the `-I` directive.

Comment: the main problem is that it would be way too tedious to go through and change all of the includes manually. even Sprite.cpp includes Sprite.h that way.

Comment: `sed` can help you, but when doing this kind of work is always good to have a backup copy ready :)

Answer (score 1):

Please remember that one usually uses `#include <filename>` directive to include files from standard include catalogues. These catalogues defined as environment variable or in command line of compiler. And `#include "filename"` to include header file from current directory or any path relative to current directory.

> without going through and doing it all manually?

You may use search&replace feature of your favourite editor

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to copy Ben's comment and say you should add an include path to where your header files are located. This is very common to do in a project