# Error in CodeBlocks C++ program and how to set default main class

Tags: boost, codeblocks

I have included the boost library in a Codeblocks c++ project.

Now, in the file

```
 boost/function.hpp
```

there is an include statement

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/iterate.hpp>
```

However I get this error in Codeblocks when I try and compile:

```
/home/arvind/Documents/Workspace/Browser/boost/function.hpp|15|fatal error:     
boost/preprocessor/iterate.hpp: No such file or directory|
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have simply included the Boost library as it is.

Also, I cannot find the screen/option to set the main class (which will actually execute).
How do I do this?(I am new to CodeBlocks hence this question).

Answer (score 0):

Your boost includes seem to be in a non-standard/system directory : `/home/arvind/Documents/Workspace/Browser`, you must tell the compiler to look there (gcc `-I` command-line switch).

Go to Project->Build Options->Search Directories->Compiler and add the directory where boost includes are. I don't have a codeblocks install right here so this was [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365014/fixing-includes-for-gcc-codeblocks).

If you can, I would recommand installing boost on your system once and for all instead of just copying files in your codeblocks workspace.